# How to work with docker containers created by cookiecutter-django?

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code

I started a project using cookiecutter-django. I use docker. I also use wsl 2 (ubuntu 20.04) on windows 10. I edit using vscode started from wsl shell.

When I create a new file using a remote docker command, e.g. when I issue  `docker-compose -f local.yml --rm django python manage.py startapp appname`
, the new files have the user and group `root`, and then I need to fix owner and group to my user to edit the files created this way.

The questions are: Is this the way I am supposed to work? Should I edit directly in the container created, so that things like mypy linting and code completion would work better hopefully. Can you give steps to do that for a docker noob?

Comment: Do you _need_ Docker here; can you do day-to-day development work in a non-Docker Python virtual environment?

Comment: For the time being I can. But just firing up `docker-compose up` is much hassle free for the first installation. Otherwise I would need to install db and connect to it too. There are other possible advantages of docker: If I manage to build a team It will be easier to share dev environment, I can mirror the deployment host system better in my development environment, etc... But I am not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

For this (and a lot of other things) you could use a bash script with bash alias to automate the process:

---

~/scripts/manage.sh

```bash
docker-compose -f local.yml --rm django python manage.py "$@"
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data ~/path_to_your_git_directory_or_project_directory
```

---

~/.bash_aliases

```bash
alias manage="source ~/scripts/manage.sh"
```

---

Once you've got these, you can either logout and log back in, or just use

```bash
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

to activate the alias.

From now on you can just use commands like this:

```bash
$ manage startapp appname
$ manage makemigrations
# etc...
```

which will

1. run the `manage.sh` script (and append any arguments to the `docker-compose` command,
2. after that, it will make your user the owner of all files (recursively) in the directory. Note that it's also useful when creating migration files.

By creating more script files and more aliases you can save yourself a lot of terminal typing. Good luck!

Comment: Please do you have an idea on how to generate new apps via ```python manage.py startapp <app-name> ```in this case? Because it appears that the examples provided in the cookie-cutter template lie under the ```<project-name-directory>/```? Will the ``` ~\scripts\manage.sh lie in the home directory? Thanks